# Plasma doesn't load properly on Kbuntu 20.04

Tags: login, kde

I was using Plasma just fine before. Now when I log in, my desktop doesn't load properly:

- Panel is drawn but is unusable
- The desktop manager draws the
  background and folders, but it's unusable
- A notification is shown
  but never goes away and floats above everything

Most things seem to work tho.

- Window manager works fine
- I can use `alt + f2`
  to launch programs

I have no clue what could be causing this. I don't remember changing any config· **Got any ideas?**

Edit: The problem only happens when I log into my user account. I tried with another user and everything is fine. The only file in my .kde directory is `share/config/kdeglobals`, which only contains stuff like GTK theme colors and widgets config.

Dolphin is extremely slow when used in my account, it freezes some time until it can open a dir. This doesn't happen when using `cd` in qterminal nor with Dolphin in a different user account. Just noticed I have other kde related files in .config which I'm going to check shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out removing ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc made my desktop work again, which meant a desktop widget was causing the issue. After playing with my widgets, it turned out the issue is the Grouping Plasmoid widget.

The problem occurs when I add  the following widgets:

```
[Containments][1][Applets][27]
immutability=1
plugin=org.kde.plasma.grouping

[Containments][28][Applets][29]
immutability=1
plugin=org.kde.plasma.notes

[Containments][28][Applets][30]
immutability=1
plugin=org.kde.plasma.calculator
```

It seems to also happen with other combinations using calculator or notes widgets inside the plasmoid container. Other widgets may also conflict.

To solve the issue, get to a terminal and either **remove the conflicting file or edit it**.

Comment: I have experienced a more severe problem (panel would not load, desktop unusable, showing just the wallpaper, while krunner would freeze when typing) that was fixed by deleting `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`. Maybe transparency widget was the culprit.